# How to delete a record from FILE *fp in C?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void Main_Menu();
void add_bookid();
void search_book();
void delete_book();
void mod_book();
void appExit();
void prompt();

typedef struct
{
   int dd;
   int mm;
   int yy;
}DATE;

struct book
{
    char author[10];
    char ID[10];
    DATE date;
    char Btitle[10];
    char Bpub[10];
};
struct book books;

int main()
{
    Main_Menu();
    return 0;
}

//Main Menu
void Main_Menu()
{
    int choice;

        while(1)
        {
            printf("\n=================================================");
            printf("\n======= INVENTORY AND MONITORING OF BOOKS =======");
            printf("\n=================================================");
            printf("\n[1] Add Book ID\n");
            printf("[2] Search Book\n");
            printf("[3] Delete a Book\n");
            printf("[4] Edit Book Info\n");
            printf("[5] Exit\n");
             printf("\n=================================================");
            printf("\nEnter your choice: ");
                scanf("%d",&choice);
             printf("\n=================================================");

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                add_bookid();
                break;
            case 2:
                search_book();
                break;
            case 3:
                delete_book();
                break;
            case 4:
                mod_book();
                break;
             case 5:
                appExit();
                break;
            default:
                printf("\n INVALID INPUT!");
                prompt();
                break;
        }
        }
}
void add_bookid()
{
    int book [10];
    int a;
    printf("\n------------------ ADD BOOKS ------------------");
    printf("\n----------You can add up to 10 books-----------");
    printf("\n=================================================");
    printf("\n How many books you will add?: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    int isFound = 0;
       for(int i=0; i<a;i++)
       {
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen("book.txt","ab+");

        fflush(stdin);
            printf("\n---------------------------------------");
            printf("\n[%d]Add Book ID: ", i+1);scanf("%s",books.ID);
            printf("\nAdd Book Title: ");scanf("%s",books.Btitle);
            printf("\nAdd Author: ");scanf("%s",books.author);
            printf("\nAdd Date of Publication: ");
            printf("\nEnter Month (MM): ");scanf("%d", &books.date.mm);
            printf("\nEnter Date (dd): ");scanf("%d", &books.date.dd);
            printf("\nEnter Year(yyyy): ");scanf("%d", &books.date.yy);
            printf("\nPublisher: ");scanf("%s",books.Bpub);
            fwrite(&books, sizeof(books), 1, fp);
        fclose(fp);
       }
        printf("\n-------------------------------------------------");
        prompt();
}
void search_book()
{
     system("cls");
     printf("\n------------------ SEARCH BOOKS ------------------");
    char b_id[10];
    int isFound = 0;
        printf("\nEnter Book ID to Search: ");fflush(stdin);
        gets(b_id);
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen("book.txt","rb");
    while(fread(&books,sizeof(books),1,fp) == 1)
    {
        if(strcmp(b_id,books.ID) == 0)
        {
            isFound = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
        if(isFound == 1)
        {
            printf("\nThe record is Found");
            printf("\n---------------------------------------");
            printf("\nBook Title:%s ", books.Btitle);
            printf("\nAuthor:%s  ", books.author);
            printf("\nDate of Publication: %d - %d - %d ", books.date.mm,books.date.dd, books.date.yy);
            printf("\nPublisher: %s ", &books.Bpub);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Sorry, No record found\n");
            printf("\n=========================================");
        }
        fclose(fp);
        printf("\n-------------------------------------------------");
            prompt(); // return to main menu
}

void delete_book()
{
    system("cls");
    printf("\n------------------ DELETE BOOKS ------------------");
    char b_id[10];
    int isFound = 0;
    printf("\nEnter Book ID to Delete: ");fflush(stdin);
    gets(b_id);
    FILE *fp, *temp;
    fp = fopen("book.txt","rb");
    temp = fopen("temp.txt", "wb");
    while(fread(&books, sizeof(books),1,fp) == 1){
        if(strcmp(b_id, books.ID) == 0){
            fwrite(&books,sizeof(books),1,temp);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(temp);
    remove("book.txt");
    rename("temp.txt","book.txt");
    printf("The record is successfully deleted");
    printf("\n-------------------------------------------------");
    prompt();
}
void mod_book()
{
     system("cls");
     printf("\n------------------ EDIT BOOK INFO ------------------");
    char b_title[10];
    int isFound = 0;
        printf("\nEnter Book Title to edit: ");fflush(stdin);
        gets(b_title);
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen("book.txt","rb+");
    while(fread(&books, sizeof(books),1,fp) == 1){
        if(strcmp(b_title, books.Btitle) == 0){
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("\nAdd New Book ID: ");scanf("%s",books.ID);
            printf("\nNew Book Title: ");scanf("%s",books.Btitle);
            printf("\nNew Author: ");scanf("%s",books.author);
            printf("\nDate of Publication: ");
            printf("\nEnter New Month (MM): ");scanf("%s", &books.date.mm);
            printf("\nEnter New Date (dd): ");scanf("%s", &books.date.dd);
            printf("\nEnter New Year(yyyy): ");scanf("%s", &books.date.yy);
            printf("\nNew Publisher: ");scanf("%s",books.Bpub);
            printf("\nInformation Successfully Edited ");
            fseek(fp,-sizeof(books), SEEK_CUR);
            fwrite(&books,sizeof(books), 1, fp);
            isFound = 1;
            break;
            }
        }
        if(!isFound){
            printf("No Record Found!");
            }
        fclose(fp);
        printf("\n-------------------------------------------------");
        prompt(); // return to main menu
}
void appExit()
{
    printf("\n == Thank you for using the App! == \n");
}
void prompt()
{
    printf("\nPress 1 if you want to go back to Main Menu, Press any key to Exit: ");
    int ans;
    scanf("%d",&ans);
    if(ans == 1)
    {
        system("cls");
        Main_Menu();
    }
   else
        appExit();
}
```

Let's say that a user add a record,
book id: 1,
title: xyxy,
author: jho,
date of publication, 12 - 12 - 2012,
then the user select another function which is 3,
delete_book,
Enter Book ID to Delete:  1.
then it will print "The record is successfully deleted"
When the user select another function, search_book();
The output should be "Sorry, No record found"
But my code still prints the recorded data even if the user already delete it.
How to fix this?

Comment: You have to read the entire file into an array, then skip that element when writing back to the file.

Comment: You might want to handle the cases when `fopen()` returns NULL.    Oh, and you don't have any comments... please make sure your indentation is neater before you hand this in too.

Comment: Consider using an existing library like sqlite3.

Comment: Technically, you only need to rewrite the tail of the file starting at the record you wanted to remove.  This means you need to keep track of the position where you read from and the position where you write to (with `fgetpos()` and `fsetpos()`).

Comment: Further, if the order in the file isn't important, you don't even need to rewrite from the deleted file on. You're using fixed-length records. that means record position in the file is literally a math equation. If order isn't important you can simply read the *last* record in the file, reposition to the location where the record which you want to 'delete' is located, overwrite it with the last-record copy you have, then truncate the file by one record width.

Comment: Fyi, neither `fflush(stdin);` nor `gets(b_title);` have any business whatsoever being in C programs. The former invokes *undefined behavior*, the latter invokes a function considered so vile and evil it has been removed from the standard library.